# Pythonic way to allow data, present in list else None

Tags: python

Let's say I have a list of data

> ["first", "second", "third"]

And I have a simple function, which receives arguments

```
def simple_function(arg1)
```

I'd like to give an argument, check if this is present in list and use it afterwards. In other case - set it to None. Something like this

```
def simple_function(arg1):
    l = ["first", "second", "third"]
    if arg1 not in l:
        arg1 = None
```

What is the most pythonic way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do:

```
arg1 = None if arg1 not in ["first", "second", "third"] else arg1
```